# How to run a TypeScript function from a package.json script

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

Currently I am running a javascript function from my package.json script, but I was looking to change it to a typescript function in a typescript file and was wondering how to adjust for that?

In javascript I have the following, which works and runs the desired function:

```
"scripts": {
    "command": "node -e 'require(\"./javaScriptFileName\").functionName()'"
}
```

The typescript file I am exporting the function from looks like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports.functionName = function(path: string): void
{
   if(fs.exists(path))
   {
       console.log("Exists");
   }
}
```

I've tried getting the ts-node package and replacing "node" with "ts-node", which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `javaScriptFileName.ts` is structured like:

```
export default {
  functionName: () => console.log('whatever')
}
```

Then can just run it via `ts-node` like you would in any typescript file: `import` the file, then run the function.

```
ts-node -e "import myLib from './javaScriptFileName'; myLib.foo()"
```

Comment: Even better, you can use [deno](https://deno.land/) instead :)

Comment: The function uses commonJS imports, so I believe the function has to be exported like
module.exports.functionName() { }. With the function exported like this, would it be possible to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I've figured it out now, make sure to have "module": "CommonJS" in your tsconfig.json under "compilerOptions" for this to work.

Comment: You can also specify CommonJS on the command line. For example, I use the following to run an AWS Lambda function `handler` export: `AWS_PROFILE=my-aws-account AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=true ts-node -O '{"module": "commonjs"}' -e 'import { handler } from "./index"; handler();'`.